# three.js: Y-rotation of group, relative to camera

Tags: three.js, rotation, euler-angles

Even after hours of googling, I can't really get my head around this. Maybe somebody here can help me a bit with this.

I basically want to **determine the Y-rotation of an object** (that is always in the viewport's center), **relative to my camera**. Imagine the object standing on the center of a record player/turntable, that slowly rotates around its Y axis, and my camera always facing the center of that object while using OrbitControls to change the cam's position around the object. Imagine the camera not moving, but the turntable turning, **one revolution equals this Y rotation to be between `0°` and `360°`**.

For example, this Y rotation would be:

- **`0°`** when cam's position is `[x=0, y=0, z=100]`, or `[x=0, y=100, z=200]` (the cam's y position doesn't matter, it always looks down/up to the group's center),
- **`45°`** when cam's position is `[x=100, y=0, z=100]` or `[x=100, y=200, z=100]`,
- **`90°`** when cam's position is `[x=100, y=0, z=0]` or `[x=200, y=100, z=0]`, etc.

Thing is, both of these can have some pretty random positions & rotations in the world coordinate system, so it's not given that the object's position is `[x=0, y=0, z=0]`.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm being helpful, but perhaps [Object3D.getWorldQuaternion](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldQuaternion) and [Quaternion.angleTo()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.angleTo) might help?

something like :

```
const cameraQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
camera.getWorldQuaternion(cameraQuaternion);

const targetQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
target.getWorldQuaternion(targetQuaternion);

const delta = cameraQuaternion.angleTo(targetQuaternion);
const euler = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(delta);

console.log(euler.y / Math.PI * 180);
```